# I got ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
a=np.arange(1,10)
b=pd.Series(a)
print(a==b)
```

output:
0. True

1. True
2. True
   ...
3. True

but when I made it in a loop

```
if (a==b):
   print('True')
```

output:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

`a==b` will give a Series, so if you want check if **all** the values are the same, try:

```
if (a==b).all():
    print('True')
```

If you want to check if **any** of the values are the same:

```
if (a==b).any():
    print('True')
```

In this case the two codes all output:

```
True
```